# SOAP service crash with empty field in request

Tags: web-services, soap

Our SOAP web service provider insist on removing empty field tags from the request because it breaks the service. Is that right practice?

See below example of request. StockID is empty tag. Should it break the SOAP service?
I would like to know best practice around empty tags in request

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">

<soap:Body xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock">
  <m:GetStockPrice>
    <m:StockName>IBM</m:StockName>
    <m:StockID/>
  </m:GetStockPrice>
</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

This Depends on how the rest of the system is programmed. There are 3 ways of sending StockID:

- Empty tag
- Tag removed
- Tag With nil="true"

What is probably happening for the first item above is that the program is deserializing the tag as an empty string, and then crashing since there is no Stock id = "".

In the 2 last items above it would deserialize as NULL and then not try and find a Stock id = NULL.